# How to run a command to run a HTTP address?

Tags: http

I have a server that sends emails and I want them to be logged into a database. I have all the actions set up, and if I open an internet window and enter http://192.168.0.2/email/getmail.php it runs the code in the PHP file and grabs any new emails from a remote mail server and downloads them into my database.

But I am having issues trying to get Windows Task Scheduler to do this task for me. I wold like it that every 10 minutes it will run this line,

```
http://192.168.0.2/email/getmail.php.
```

I set up this code I found on here into a text file and saved it as a vbs file, the Task scheduler runs the vbs file and it works for the first time, but it stays as Running in the status. So 10 minutes later it will not start to run again as it already is running and so it will not get new mails.

```
Set oX = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHTTP")
oX.Open "GET", "http://192.168.0.2/email/getmail.php", False
oX.Send ""
WScript.Echo oX.responseText
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the actual script it's probably that echo comment as it will be waiting for a response - which might not even be presented to screen when using the scheduler. Run it without that wscript echo line.